# Cannot create a UIButton using declaration

Tags: uibutton, swift2

I am trying to create a `UIButton` by trying to initialise in a `viewController` as shown below. However, I am getting `cannot convert value of type () -> _ to specified type UIButton` error which I don't have idea how I stuck into.

```
let loginRegisterButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .System)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 80, g: 101, b: 161)
    button.setTitle("Register", forState: .Normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}
```

This is the sample code and I have used a `UIColor` extension and I have attached the screenshot of error herewith.

[image]

As far as I know, this is not a syntax error, but I have no idea what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to add

> ()

at the end
Use Below code ,

```
let loginRegisterButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .System)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 80, g: 101, b: 161)
    button.setTitle("Register", forState: .Normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()
```

What you are missing is mentioned in the error message, that you are  assigning closure to `UIButton` instance. By adding () this will create instance of `UIButton`.

Comment: Please also support your answer with explanation that way it would be of a great help to other learners.